# add new lines to text file and get lines from last adding

Tags: php

I am working on simple debug script that would allow me (when save button is pushed) to add new lines to `.txt` file and then on page load, get whatever was saved last time.

so for example i have my `user_input.txt` file and when i press save - i am adding timestamp and textarea contents to this file. When page is loaded again, i am getting contents from last save.

For the moment i have this code for get:

```
$current_user_input = file_get_contents('user_input.txt');
if($current_user_input === false) {
    $current_user_input = '';
}
```

and for to set:

```
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['user_input']) {
        $file = 'user_input.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $_POST['user_input']);
    }
}
```

Obviously for the moment its just overwriting the text file and getting all its content, how do i modify it so it does what i described above?

Comment: [`file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: ok so i guess this solves problem of adding into file instead of appending, but how to then get from this last save instead all of its contents and also does this creates file if it doesnt exists ?

Comment: You want to save as `JSON`. Then you can get the last `element` in `array`. Also: FILE_APPEND If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the save, you need to append the data (as AjAX's comment says using `FILE_APPEND`), but also adding an end of line to ensure that they appear on separate lines.

```
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['user_input']) {
        $file = 'user_input.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $_POST['user_input'].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the last line using `file()` which reads the file in line by line into an array and take the last element...

```
$oldInput = file($file);
if(!empty($oldInput)) {
    $current_user_input = array_pop($oldInput);
}
else {
    $current_user_input = '';
}
```

Update:
For multi-line content you could change the new lines to `<br />` tags...

```
file_put_contents($file, 
        str_replace( PHP_EOL, '<br />', $_POST['user_input']).PHP_EOL, 
        FILE_APPEND);
```

Which would keep all content on a single line.

Comment: I was just about to start typing an answer like this.

Comment: The only problem is that when user types with multi line in textarea and then saves, his save can have for example 10 or 12 lines or 20, so in that case since i dont know how many lines textarea contents will have i have to store some flag during save and read from last flag or something like that right ? This trick that you suggested would only work for one line saves

Comment: You could replace new lines with `<br>` tags (see updated answer).

Comment: You may need to use `str_replace( "\n", '<br />', $_POST['user_input'])` which is less prone to only working with one platform (some use `\n\r` some use `\n`)